# Compound Angles

Tags: trigonometry

I was working on compound angles formula problems, when I encountered this problem:

$\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{9}\right)$

$\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{18}\right)$

I know how to use the formula, but I'm not sure how to break up these two angles into simplified angles in order to calculate the value without a calculator .

Comment: Is this two separate questions, to compute each of the sine and cosine terms? Or in the problem are the two expressions combined in some expression?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{5\pi}{9}=\frac{10\pi}{18}$, so $$\frac{5\pi}{9}-\frac{7\pi}{18}=\frac{3\pi}{18}=\frac{\pi}{6}.$$